# how to ask cat (and maybe grep ?) not to take into account a new line when it's inside double quotes?

Tags: bash, grep, cat, newlines

I have a large `csv` file that starts this way :

```
codeRegion,nomEPCI,codeDepartement,nomCommune,populationTotale,titre,objet,site_web,libelle_objet_social1,libelle_objet_social2,siret,numero_waldec,nombreAnneesExistence,date_creation,nombreAnneesDerniereDeclaration,date_derniere_declaration,position_activite,date_dissolution,codeCommune,adresse_siege_complement,adresse_siege_numero_voie,adresse_siege_type_voie,adresse_siege_libelle_voie,adresse_siege_distribution,adresse_siege_code_postal,nom_declarant,adresse_gestion_complement_association,adresse_gestion_complement_geo,adresse_gestion_libelle_voie,adresse_gestion_distribution_facturation,adresse_gestion_code_postal,adresse_gestion_achemine,adresse_gestion_pays,civilite_declarant,codeEPCI
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,ABSOLU MAS/KA,"organiser des manifestations sociales et culturelles ainsi que des activités de loisirs","",Action socio-culturelle,"Clubs de loisirs, relations","",W9G2015492,0.5808219178082191,2020-02-05,0.5808219178082191,2020-02-05,A,0001-01-01,97101,62 Résidence les Lavandes,62,RES,Boisripeaux,_Boisripeaux,97139,"","",RÉSIDENCE LES LAVANDES,62  RESIDENCE BOISRIPEAUX,"",97139,LES ABYMES,FRANCE,PM,200018653
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,AMBITION PLUS DE TERRASSON,proposer des activités sportives et culturelles,"",Action socio-culturelle,"Sports, activités de plein air","",W9G2015457,0.6356164383561644,2020-01-16,0.6356164383561644,2020-01-16,A,0001-01-01,97101,Maison Andreopa Marcel,3,CHEM1,"Route de Terrasson, Rue Albert Léogane",_97139,97139,"","",MAISON ANDREOPA MARCEL,3  CHEMIN ROUTE DE TERRASSO,"",97139,LES ABYMES,FRANCE,PF,200018653
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,ASSOCIATION SYNDICALE DE LA RESIDENCE MORNE CARUEL,gérer et d'entretenir les espaces communs cette mission ne comporte pas la possibilité daliéner les espaces indivis si ce n'est au profit de la commune,"",Actions de sensibilisation et d'éducation à l'environnement et au développement durable,"","",W9G2015446,14.797260273972602,2005-11-21,14.797260273972602,2005-11-21,A,0001-01-01,97101,residence morne caruel,"","","",_,97139,"",residence morne caruel,"","","",97139,Les   Abymes,FRANCE,PM,200018653
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,ASSOCIATION SPORTIVE DU LYCEE POLYVALENT CHEVALIER DE SAINT-GEORGES,"organiser et développer en prolongement de l'éducation physique et sportive donnée pendant les heures de scolarité, l'initiation et la pratique sportive pour les élèves qui y adhèrent elle représente l'établissement dans les épreuves sportives scolaires","",Activités de plein air (dont saut à l'élastique),"Centres de loisirs, clubs de loisirs multiples","",W9G2002394,19.87123287671233,2000-10-26,4.742465753424658,2015-12-09,A,0001-01-01,97101,"","",BD,des Héros,_Baimbridge,97139,"","",LYCéE POLYVALENT CHEVALIER SAINT-GEORG,BOULEVARD DES HéROS,BAIMBRIDGE,97139,ABYMES,FRANCE,PM,200018653
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,"LOISIRS, COMPETITIONS, CLUB (LO. CO. CLUB)","participer aux competitions cyclistes
 organiser des manifesta- tions sportives a caractere promotionnel.","",Activités de plein air (dont saut à l'élastique),"Centres de loisirs, clubs de loisirs multiples","",W9G2010818,28.747945205479454,1991-12-13,27.378082191780823,1993-04-26,A,0001-01-01,97101,"","","","",_,97139,"","","","","",97139,LES ABYMES,FRANCE,PM,200018653
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,ASSOCIATION ETUDIANTE DE TOURISME ET DE LOISIRS.( A.T.O.L.),réunir les anciens élèves ayant eu une formation de tourisme et de loisirs et de promouvoir les actions du brevet de technicien supérieur de tourisme et de loisir,"","Amicales, personnel d’établissements scolaires ou universitaires","Syndicats d'initiative, offices de tourisme, salons du tourisme","",W9G2011048,24.53698630136986,1996-02-27,24.53150684931507,1996-02-29,A,0001-01-01,97101,"","","",Ecole superieure des cadres et techniciens,_Route de la rocade grand-camp,97139,"","","",Ecole superieure des cadres et technic,Route de la rocade grand-camp,97139,LES ABYMES,FRANCE,PM,200018653
```

It's fifth line of data has a description, between double quotes, containing a new line. It works perfectly with *Excel* or *LibreCalc*.

I need to retain only the lines that are starting by a specific French region. For example here, the '01' one (Guadeloupe).
I execute :

```bsh
# Get the CSV header
head -n1 associations_touristiques.csv > associations_touristiques_gua.csv

# Extract data of region '01'
cat associations_touristiques.csv | grep -a '^01,' >> associations_touristiques_gua.csv
```

But my final `csv` is broken.

```
codeRegion,nomEPCI,codeDepartement,nomCommune,populationTotale,titre,objet,site_web,libelle_objet_social1,libelle_objet_social2,siret,numero_waldec,nombreAnneesExistence,date_creation,nombreAnneesDerniereDeclaration,date_derniere_declaration,position_activite,date_dissolution,codeCommune,adresse_siege_complement,adresse_siege_numero_voie,adresse_siege_type_voie,adresse_siege_libelle_voie,adresse_siege_distribution,adresse_siege_code_postal,nom_declarant,adresse_gestion_complement_association,adresse_gestion_complement_geo,adresse_gestion_libelle_voie,adresse_gestion_distribution_facturation,adresse_gestion_code_postal,adresse_gestion_achemine,adresse_gestion_pays,civilite_declarant,codeEPCI
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,ABSOLU MAS/KA,"organiser des manifestations sociales et culturelles ainsi que des activités de loisirs","",Action socio-culturelle,"Clubs de loisirs, relations","",W9G2015492,0.5808219178082191,2020-02-05,0.5808219178082191,2020-02-05,A,0001-01-01,97101,62 Résidence les Lavandes,62,RES,Boisripeaux,_Boisripeaux,97139,"","",RÉSIDENCE LES LAVANDES,62  RESIDENCE BOISRIPEAUX,"",97139,LES ABYMES,FRANCE,PM,200018653
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,AMBITION PLUS DE TERRASSON,proposer des activités sportives et culturelles,"",Action socio-culturelle,"Sports, activités de plein air","",W9G2015457,0.6356164383561644,2020-01-16,0.6356164383561644,2020-01-16,A,0001-01-01,97101,Maison Andreopa Marcel,3,CHEM1,"Route de Terrasson, Rue Albert Léogane",_97139,97139,"","",MAISON ANDREOPA MARCEL,3  CHEMIN ROUTE DE TERRASSO,"",97139,LES ABYMES,FRANCE,PF,200018653
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,ASSOCIATION SYNDICALE DE LA RESIDENCE MORNE CARUEL,gérer et d'entretenir les espaces communs cette mission ne comporte pas la possibilité daliéner les espaces indivis si ce n'est au profit de la commune,"",Actions de sensibilisation et d'éducation à l'environnement et au développement durable,"","",W9G2015446,14.797260273972602,2005-11-21,14.797260273972602,2005-11-21,A,0001-01-01,97101,residence morne caruel,"","","",_,97139,"",residence morne caruel,"","","",97139,Les   Abymes,FRANCE,PM,200018653
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,ASSOCIATION SPORTIVE DU LYCEE POLYVALENT CHEVALIER DE SAINT-GEORGES,"organiser et développer en prolongement de l'éducation physique et sportive donnée pendant les heures de scolarité, l'initiation et la pratique sportive pour les élèves qui y adhèrent elle représente l'établissement dans les épreuves sportives scolaires","",Activités de plein air (dont saut à l'élastique),"Centres de loisirs, clubs de loisirs multiples","",W9G2002394,19.87123287671233,2000-10-26,4.742465753424658,2015-12-09,A,0001-01-01,97101,"","",BD,des Héros,_Baimbridge,97139,"","",LYCéE POLYVALENT CHEVALIER SAINT-GEORG,BOULEVARD DES HéROS,BAIMBRIDGE,97139,ABYMES,FRANCE,PM,200018653
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,"LOISIRS, COMPETITIONS, CLUB (LO. CO. CLUB)","participer aux competitions cyclistes
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,ASSOCIATION ETUDIANTE DE TOURISME ET DE LOISIRS.( A.T.O.L.),réunir les anciens élèves ayant eu une formation de tourisme et de loisirs et de promouvoir les actions du brevet de technicien supérieur de tourisme et de loisir,"","Amicales, personnel d’établissements scolaires ou universitaires","Syndicats d'initiative, offices de tourisme, salons du tourisme","",W9G2011048,24.53698630136986,1996-02-27,24.53150684931507,1996-02-29,A,0001-01-01,97101,"","","",Ecole superieure des cadres et techniciens,_Route de la rocade grand-camp,97139,"","","",Ecole superieure des cadres et technic,Route de la rocade grand-camp,97139,LES ABYMES,FRANCE,PM,200018653
01,CA CAP Excellence,971,Abymes,54049,ASSOCIATION AMICALE DES AGENTS D'ENTRETIEN DE LA MUNICIPALITE DES ABYMES.,"realiser des rencontres et echanges d'ordre culturel, sportif, social avec toutes categories de personnel communal et autres associations ou groupements.","",Association du personnel d'une entreprise (hors caractère syndical),"Comités de défense et d'animation de quartier, association locale ou municipale","",W9G2012061,31.56986301369863,1989-02-16,31.56986301369863,1989-02-16,A,0001-01-01,97101,"","","","",_,97139,"","","","","",97139,LES ABYMES,FRANCE,PM,200018653
```

Tthe line 5 is truncated after *cyclistes*.

What the proper way to make `cat` command not taking into account a newline when it is inside double quotes,
and is it needed to change the `grep` command too after that, and if so : how ?

Comment: Do you have access to `csvgrep` (from the Python-based `csvkit`)?

Comment: I would suggest you to try to write the questions so that we have a minimal/shorter example. I believe there is a large energy barrier to parse it (see "scroll the horizontal bar") that would drive off many readers, although I find your question interesting.

Comment: @steeldriver No I do not have access to `csvgrep`.

Comment: In addition to what @Quasímodo said, when asking about categorizing data it would be helpful to include at least one case from each category (i.e. in this case, one or more records that do **not** match your search pattern)

Comment: @steeldriver It wasn't possible due to the size of the file.

Comment: @Marc yes it is possible, just make up something minimal that's representative of your real data with respect to the problem specific you're asking for help with. See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/610962/133219.

Comment: short answer: no, neither cat nor grep are capable of this. You need a fully-fledged CSV parser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
awk '/^01/||n%2{print;n+=gsub(/"/,"&")}' file
```

For each line,

- `/^01/||n%2` If line begins with `01` or `n` (initally zero) is odd,

  - `print` Print it
  - `n+=gsub(/"/,"&")` increment `n` by the return value of the `gsub` function.
    This replaces every double-quote `/"/` with itself `"&"`. That would be pointless, indeed, but it also returns the number of substitutions made, so it is a way of counting the number of double-quotes in the line.

Notice that if the `n` is odd (`n%2`) the line does not have a closing double-quote, so it keeps printing until `n` is even, regardless of whether there is a `/^01/` match on the next lines.

A side-by-side diff for you:

```
$ diff -yW 30 <(cat file) <(awk '/^01/||n%2{print;n+=gsub(/"/,"&")}' file)
04,xde        <
01,abc"         01,abc"
cd              cd
as"             as"
02,dsad       <
03,1ad"       <
01,as,"as       01,as,"as
us"             us"
02,s          <
01,a            01,a
```

Comment: Impressive ! It's working ! I am quite unable to understand `awk` syntax, but I'll check this more in detail and thank you again.

Comment: Note that this theoretically fails with a quote-count of 2^53 + 1, because awk numbers are `double` precision floating point.  [Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3793838).  Above that point, only even integers are representable.  (Unlike if `n` was a fixed-width integer, in which case it would just wrap and that would be fine.)  But fortunately 2^53 is huge enough not to be a practical concern. And maybe awk interpreters use integers internally if you never do any division or any non-integer stuff, I didn't check.

Comment: This will fail if your flavour of CSV allows backslash-escaped double quotes inside quoted fields. `"abc\"def"`. Could be easily fixed using a lookbehind assertion, but I don't know any AWK interpreter that supports them. So if this is a concern, you have to resort to something ugly like `/(^")|([^\\]")/`.

Comment: @TooTea I also point out that there is no account of single-quoted double-quotes in this answer, which simply answers what the question asks and nothing more. For a tool that will offer more versatility, see Kusalananda's answer.

Answer (score 13):

Using `csvgrep` from the [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to pull out all records that has a `codeRegion` value containing the string `01`:

```
csvgrep -c codeRegion -m 01 file.csv
```

This is using a proper CSV parser, so there will no issues with newlines or commas in properly quoted fields.

The `-c` option selects the column that we'd like to investigate, by number or by name, and `-m` designates the string to match with.  One could also use `-r` to match with a regular expression, e.g. `-r '^01$'` to avoid matching strings where `01` is a substring (as in `011`).  See `csvgrep --help`.

Comment: I tried an `apt-get install csvgrep` but `csvgrep` package wasn't among those available to my *Debian*.

Comment: @Marc [the package is called `csvkit`](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=csvgrep&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=amd64)